# ODBC source doesn't receive dynamic variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am designing an incremental load for my ETL solution in SSIS. For that, I have an Execute SQL task that gets the maximum load time from the data warehouse and then stores it in a package variable, which is already set to evaluate as expression.

Then I have set the ODBC source's sql command property to an expression that has my query and the variable. However, I have looked into the variable during debug and when I run the package it seems that this variable doesn't get used in the sql command, instead it remains null.

I have already tried setting the variable property 'EvaluateAsExpression' to True, I have tried storing the query in a different variable and then setting that as the sql command for my ODBC source.

Comment: Without you showing what you've done, this is impossible for us to answer. Why have you tagged MySQL as well? What dose this have to do with it? Thanks,

Comment: We'll need more info.  Maybe screenshots of your variables, how the execute SQL task is configured and the ODBC sql command expression.